Resolve "GPG Key check Error" updating packages
I'm trying to update node on an existing server from v20.10.0 to v20.12.2 using
sudo dnf update.
But get the following error:
Node.js Packages for Linux RPM based distros - x86_64                                                                                                                            1.6 MB/s | 1.7 kB     00:00
GPG key at file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/NODESOURCE-NSOLID-GPG-SIGNING-KEY-EL (0x9B1BE0B4) is already installed
The GPG keys listed for the "Node.js Packages for Linux RPM based distros - x86_64" repository are already installed but they are not correct for this package.
Check that the correct key URLs are configured for this repository.. Failing package is: nodejs-2:20.12.2-1nodesource.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/NODESOURCE-NSOLID-GPG-SIGNING-KEY-EL
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
Error: GPG check FAILED

Is there a way to update the GPG Keys? And if so how?

The error "GPG check FAILED" indicates a issue with the package signature verification. Try any and all of these fixes to fix your issue:
Update the DNF package manager: Run sudo dnf update dnf to ensure you're using the latest version.
Clean the DNF cache: Run sudo dnf clean all to remove any corrupted or outdated package metadata.
Disable GPG checking: Run sudo dnf update --nogpgcheck to temporarily bypass the GPG signature verification. (Note: This reduces security, so use with caution.)
Update Node.js: Run sudo dnf update nodejs to try updating Node.js again.
Check for conflicting packages: Run sudo dnf repoquery --conflicts nodejs to identify any conflicting packages that might be causing the issue.
Try a different update method: If the above steps fail, try using sudo yum update nodejs or sudo dnf upgrade nodejs instead.
If none of these steps resolve your issue, you could try to investigate further by checking the package manager logs or seeking assistance from a system administrator or the Node.js community (if you haven’t done this already?)
Hope I could help- if none of this works, then I’m stumped!

Thanks all other packages on the system were already up to date. The --nogpgcheck flag was the help I needed. I'm surprised I didn't find that in my searching. Ultimately I just ran sudo dnf update nodejs --nogpgcheck.
It would be nice if there were any easy way to just update the GPG key but this works for now.

No worries, glad I could help. You can also always try the alternate update method too!
